# How to check photo is already present in photo library using URL or some other key using photos framework IOS 8?

Tags: ios, photosframework

Just like in ALAssetlibrary using

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagePath]
         resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
```

i was able to fetch the photo to match or to check if the photo is present.
Similarly how to check if the photo is present and to fetch the photo using URL or with any other key info which we obtain using

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager]
                     requestImageDataForAsset:asset
                     options:imageRequestOptions
                     resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI,
                                     UIImageOrientation orientation,
                                     NSDictionary *info)
                     {

                         NSLog(@"info = %@", info);

                     }];
```

Comment: What do you mean by already present?

Comment: I mean i have a list of photos info,which i have accessed using the above code. If their is a scenario like to check particular photo is already present  in the photo library with such info(basically like a key ,name ,URL anyother).

Comment: scenario like if user deleted photo, and i want to remove from my list of info.

Comment: You have an array of PHAsset, you can use `asset.localIdentifier` to identify it. I don't know if the user is using your app to delete a photo.